# How do I find information about discontinued LEGO sets?

Tags: piece-information, lego-group

I have some older LEGO sets that have been discontinued for a while.

I am trying to find information like # of pieces and some other info.

Looking them up on the LEGO website didn't work. Is there anywhere else that I could find info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome William. Please check out either [Brickset](http://brickset.com) or [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com) to find this information. Both websites have a big database containing tons of information on LEGO sets and LEGO parts. BrickLink is more comprehensive, but a little bit more difficult to navigate.

Comment: Thanks! That answers it. The websites have exactly what I want!